# Window.open opening page in another tab but manually entering URL in new tab redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, google-chrome, window.open

**Background:**

I am handling authentication in my project using Authentication Handler class. The logic is: token created during login will be verified and if it is valid, then only access to required  APIs will be given.

**Scenario:**

I am logged in the application with valid credentials(I have a token created during login).
If I open a page in another tab from the app (using window.open(address, "_blank")), it is opening that page. But when I manually open another tab on browser and enter the same address in address bar, ,it is redirecting me to login page.

**Question:**

Isn't opening page using window.open and manually entering address in address bar the same thing? Why am I able to open page using window.open but not manually entering same URL by opening new tab?

Comment: Found out that "Duplicating a tab copies the tab's sessionStorage into the new tab." When I am doing windows.open, it is duplication tab and thus copying session storage into new tab.